# std out of range size terminated

Tags: c++

hi guys i write this code for get string with space(with getline function), but when i set size from cin to 3 and next write my string inline like "red riding hood" i will get error, i think the problem is in my first for statement, do you know how to fix it?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>  //farzad filmbin
int main(){
    int size = 0;
    std::cin>>size;
    char *first = new char[size];
    auto *name = new std::string[size];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
        getline(std::cin, name[i]);
        //std::cin>>name[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        transform(name[i].begin(), name[i].end(), name[i].begin(), ::tolower);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        first[i] = static_cast<char>(toupper(name[i].at(0)));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        std::cout<<first[i]<<name[i].substr(1,*name[i].end()-1)<<std::endl;
    }
    delete [] first;
    delete [] name;

}
```

Comment: you use `size` for both the number of characters and for the number of words. "red riding hood" is 3 words with 3,6 and 4 characters

Comment: why do you use `char *first = new char[size];` when it can be a `std::string` ?

Comment: Substr takes a size as the second parameter. Try using .size() instead of .end()

Comment: This is a lot of unnecessary code for a simple problem. You should replace `new[]` with `std::vector`, and get rid of the `first[]` array completely, and just replace the 1st character of each `name[]` string, no need to use `substr()`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that with the `std::cin>>size` you start to read a line, and I think you put a newline after that so your input is like

"3

red

riding

hood"

then the first `getline` will read the first line after the character '3' (because you read that) so an empty line. so `name` will be `["","red","riding"]`.

In the third loop you call `name[0].at(0)` what is invalid since `name[0]==""` Therefore it throws an exception.

The things to learn are 1)  think about empty strings (you could also have an empty-string in the input) 2) `cin>>` doesn`t eat the withespace after and` getline` will read the end of the same line.

So to fix it check if `name[i]==""` in the first loop and if it is empty decrease i so you will read a new one to its place

Comment: no difference, i think u didnt undrestand my question

Comment: can you send me an exact input where your program chrashes if you include `if (name[i]==""){i--;} after the getline?
`